# How should I show a button in a website with a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to inject a button on a specific location in a website.
I want the user (that has the chrome extension) to see the button when the website is loaded.

I tried to create a function with js that triggers on window.load. But sometimes it throws an error because the id (in getElementById) is not found (but it exists).

Comment: Use MutationObserver to wait for this element.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you wait for the page to load before you inject the button. You can do this by wrapping your injecting button code around a listener to DOMContentLoaded (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event):

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  // you code that finds the element with an id and injects the button
})
```